# I don't know what is the difference between two declaration in python 2-d array

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
from pprint import pprint

N = 4
M = 5

visited = [[False] * M for _ in range(N)]
visited2 = [[False] * M] * N

visited[3][2] = True
visited2[3][2] = True

pprint(visited)
pprint(visited2)

print(len(visited))
print(len(visited2))
```

I don't know why two computation show other results.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHCAa.png)

Comment: Please paste your result as text in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)